# How to send a image to another page using phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, cordova

I am very new to using HTML, CSS and JS etc in Phone gap.

I have no idea how to approach this problem. i have done some research but it doesn't make sense to me.

I have a page of small symbols

```
<a href="largeSymbol.html" class="symbol"> <img src="img/car.png" alt="car"></a> 
<a href="largeSymbol.html" class="symbol"> <img src="img/lorry.png" alt="lorry"></a> 
<a href="largeSymbol.html" class="symbol"> <img src="img/house.png" alt="house"></a>
```

When the user clicks one of these symbol I want the image to be sent to the large symbol page where it will show the symbol enlarged.

If the user goes back and chooses another symbol i want it to overwrite this image.

how can i code this into my application?

I initially thought i could create a enlarged symbol page for each symbol but this would mean there would be over 300 pages. Therefore why im trying to figure out how to use one enlarged symbol page which all the symbols can be enlarged and seen on.

Comment: You could redirect to `largeSymbol.html?file=img/car.png`, and `largeSymbol.html` would just query the image via Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a query string parameter to your links

```
<a href="largeSymbol.html?src=/img/car.png" class="symbol"> <img src="img/car.png" alt="car"></a> 
<a href="largeSymbol.html?src=/img/car.png" class="symbol"> <img src="img/lorry.png" alt="lorry"></a> 
<a href="largeSymbol.html?src=/img/car.png" class="symbol"> <img src="img/house.png" alt="house"></a>
```

Then on **largeSymbol.html** you can use the [URI.js](https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/) library to read the query string and act accordingly, maybe something like this

```
<img id='big-image' src='' />
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/URI.js/1.17.0/URI.js'></script>

<script>
    var querySrc = URI( window.location.href ).search( true ).src;
    $("#big-image").attr( "src" , querySrc );
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, it is now solved and working. Thank you so much i appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: No problem, if you used my solution please consider marking this as the correct answer :)